# connotation of тоска

Tags: перевод, значения, connotation

Looking for a word for *longing, yearning* I found `желание` and `стремление`. However,  these seem somehow too shallow for the given use case.

Actually I'd like to use `тоска` but this word possibly has a negative or melancholic connotation which is also not what I'm looking for. Is that so?

- Is there any other alternative to express a profound yearning / longing?
- What verb would be used with `тоска` and/or any alternative to say *quench the yearning*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"тоска", mysterious as it is, is associated with melancholical, kinda depressing yearning for thing to be better/more in line with what you want. SO it may mean two things: "yearning/depression" and just "boredom" (then it is the same as "скука")

If what you mean is a strong, emotionally "painful" desire for something that is, perhaps, out of your reach, and has been so, then "тоска" is kind of a right word. **"Заглушить тоску"** will work (though, I just made it up, and it sounds as a "temporary" solution).

Желание is "wish, desire" and "стремление" is more like "striving, aspiration" and even "intention" in some context, i.e. something that makes you strive for something (whil "тоска" is a passive thing)

So.. what is the meaning of your "quench the yearning"? Is it the same as "quench your thirst" (satisfy it) or "quench the disire" ("kill" it). Or maybe "shut off" your desire if only temporary?

The alternative words for profound yearnung:

- острое/сильное желание
- жажда (lit. "thirst", a strong and sometimes active desire)
- стремление (if it is active! And only then)

Comment: *for something that is, perhaps, out of your reach* ... *and it sounds as a "temporary" solution* okay, I see. Then maybe rather `воплотить желание` or `утолять жажду`. If these can be put/understood in a non fleshly sense, that'd be fine.

Comment: "воплотить" explicitly means that you *fulfil* your desire, make it real (плоть = flesh, i.e. make your "dream" a material, "physical" thing). "Утолить" is kinda ambiguus in just how permanent it is, but also suggests that you use a "direct approach", i.e. do just the thing you desire. Is this *really* the meaning you hand in mind?

Comment: as you point it out, I'll stick to `воплотить желание`. Seems to fit best. Can I use `выполнение` in a similar, general way for fulfillment of `желания` or is that impossible?

Comment: The verb "выполнять" (from which the noun "выполнение" is formed) is more like "to carry out, to implement, to execute". To do something according to some instructions You can "выполнять" commands or other people's wishes, but with your own that doesn't sound right. There is also "исполнять" — to fulfil or grant wish (someone else). Djinns often do this :). 

So, long story short, "выполнение" only works when someone carries out an instruction or wish when told so by someone else. Исполнение can work both ways.

Comment: You can also use "Желание исполнилось/сбылось" ("The wish has come true") just not to bother with these awkward constructions.

Comment: The best way to use work "выполнять" in case of "выполнять мечту". And the best combination with word "Желание" are "Исполнить желание", "Достичь желаемого"

Comment: "выполнять мечту" sounds weird.

Comment: It's just, that `желание` may also be associated with fleshly desires, but maybe not necessarily? Probably right understanding has to be made clear by context.

Comment: It may or may not. Just a basic word for "wish, desire" which covers its many meanings. The word can mean fleshly desires if you are talking about sex and relationships and doesn't mean it if you don't. I'd say that when you just say a single word "желание" without any context, I don't perceive it as having a sexual connotation at all.

Answer (score 1):

if what you're after is both longing and yearning, then `тоска` fits the bill

Answer (score 1):

'Влечение' and its weaker form 'увлечение'. Both could be used to express yearning/longing to something or somebody (with 'влечение', in the latter case it could also bear subtle sexual context).

Answer (score 0):

You could try "стремительное желание" if that works for you. One word translations are sometimes inadequate. English tends to be a bit more terse/efficient - able to get more meaning into a smaller space.

Comment: Спасибо, очень смешно! :) Я бы все-таки переставил слова местами: сильное желание, страстное стремление, страстное желание, сильное стремление.